# Postgresql in generating crosstab results

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table like below:

```
| Email   | Category  | Amount    | Post_date    |    
| 123@234 | ATM       | 20        | 2016-09-20   |
| 234@345 | POS       | 30        | 2016-09-21   |
| 345@567 | FOOD      | 40        | 2016-09-22   |
| 567@789 | ENTE      | 50        | 2016-09-23   |
```

I Want the output look like this:

```
| Email   | Category    | Last 1 day| Last 3 days  |  last 5 days |  
| 123@234 | ATM amount  | 20        |    40        |      50      |
|         | POS amount  | 0         |    30        |      40      |
|         | ATM count   | 2         |    3         |      3       |
|         | POS count   | 0         |    0         |      3       |
```

I can write a query to generate one column at once, such as last 1 days, last 3 day, etc.

My questions are :

1. I don't know how to put the results from (last 1 day, last 3 days, etc.) together?
2. And I don't know how can I pivot the column (ATM Count) into rows.

Comment: What is the relationship between your sample data and your results?  It makes no sense.

Comment: Hi Gordon, the ATM mount is the dollar spent by the person (identified by email) during the past 1,3,5,etc. days. The count means how many times the person uses the card on ATM/POS during the past 1,3,5, etc. days

Answer (score 0):

I strongly suspect that you want a query like this:

```
select email, category,
       sum(case when post_date >= current_date - interval '1 day' then 1 else 0 end) as last_1,
       sum(case when post_date >= current_date - interval '3 day' then 1 else 0 end) as last_3,
       sum(case when post_date >= current_date - interval '5 day' then 1 else 0 end) as last_5
from t
group by email, category;
```

I admit this is speculation, because the question is not clear.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. However, the result should not be grouped by "category" because the category in the output is different from the one in the original table. ATM amount (output table) = sum(amount) where category = ATM in the original table. and the results should show both sum (amount) as ATM amount and count(amount) as ATM count as is shown in your query. Thank you again for your help!